# %DATE% Batch Variable not working in Windows 10

Tags: date, batch-file, windows-10

%DATE% Batch Variable not working in Windows 10

I created a batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
C:
MKDIR C:\BACKUP
CD C:\BACKUP
ECHO backing up, plz wait...
MKDIR bkup-%date%
cd bkup-%date%
```

But I get an error saying: "The syntax of the command is incorrect." error.

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: type `echo %date%` and you will probably see illegal filename characters

Comment: yup, I see 12/08/2015

Comment: Dude, but how can I format the date like 12-08-2015 ?

Comment: Solved: set datetimef=%date:~-4%_%date:~3,2%_%date:~0,2%_%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%

Comment: `MKDIR bkup-%date:/=-%`

Answer (score 4):

```
rem only WINDOWS 10

CLS
@echo off


ECHO %DATE%

ECHO.

ECHO %TIME%

ECHO.

set mydate=%date:~11,4%-%date:~8,2%-%date:~5,2%

echo %mydate%

PAUSE

EXIT
```

Comment: To convert date Tue. 14/05/2019  to  2019-05-14

Answer (score 3):

Solved!, I found a post:

```
set datetimef=%date:~-4%_%date:~3,2%_%date:~0,2%_%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%
echo datetimef
```

This solve my issue, thanks.

Comment: Would anyone be willing to expand on this answer? For example, why does it work? What date format does it produce?

Answer (score 1):

On my system, the format of the date when you used `%date%` on Windows 8 was `MM/dd/yyyy` (e.g. `02/23/2016`) but after upgrading to Windows 10 it displayed as `Day MM/dd/yy` (e.g. `Tue 02/23/16`) instead. This caused  `/` characters in folder paths in my script which made it fail. In the `Start > Settings > Time & Language > Date & time` settings, I noticed that the format for `Short date` had changed to the `M/d/yy` option. When I reset the option to `MM/dd/yyyy` the format for `%date%` returned to `MM/dd/yyyy` and my program which grabbed the date parts based on that format worked properly again.

If you want to set a custom date format, you can go to `Region > Additional settings... > Date tab` and set a custom format for `Short date` which will then be used for the command prompt `%date%` printout.

Answer (score 1):

use character substitution: %date:/=-%

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it using `%%B` instead of `%date%` (Leonardo's answer didn't work for me on windows 7). [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/oez5sb4v/)

Comment: `%%B` is a `for` variable. Without context, this answer is as useful as "I solved it with some code"

Comment: @Stephan Strange (but I'm not a programer). I simply replace the %date% by %%B in the path of the destination folder of the copy command (in the bat above, which works). %date% did give me an error.